# Best practice for building single window interface with four collection views

Tags: ios

I'm trying to build an interface that has two horizontally scrolling collection views, but I'm still torn between having two separate view controllers control their respective views or controlling the two views within the main view controller.

People, at least in the past, have said having a controller that controls only a fraction of the screen is not good practice. But I also have a feeling that's only a relic of pre-iOS 5 days.

The thing with controlling two rows of collection view is the data source object, in this case the main view controller, gets very confusing and it's hard to pass on data to subviews of collection views because I have to check which collection view is sending the message and such.

I asked a similar question in the past but the thread got blocked or something. Please don't. I don't see anything wrong with the question and I've been pulling my hair for so long.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, use two ViewControllers, one for each CollectionView.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of hair pulling and experiments, and reading posts about table views embedded in other table views, it seems that the best way to do it is have one main view controller control all the subviews.

I tried adding collection view controllers as child view controllers, and setting the frame and layout and everything, but they will always end up weird. It does seem Apple doesn't allow for view controllers to control only a small portion (I may be wrong, but based on my experience with UICollectionViewController this is the case).

The problem with identifying which view is which in the data source methods, you can use the tag property.